# C++ vector to pointer of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Is there a way to convert a vector to a pointer to a pointer (ptr-to-ptr).

Background:
I have an arbitrary length set of data stored in a vector. But I have a library of algorithms that accept ptr-to-ptr (for image array access). I need to get the data from my vector to a ptr-to-ptr. How is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a function `void f(int **array)` and a vector `std::vector<int*> vect` you can call f like this: `f(&vect[0])`. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Actually, yes. That is what I'm looking for. I didn't think to try that. thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the `vect.data()` do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can convert a vector to a const pointer-to-array using the `c_str()` member function.

EDIT: Oops! I meant `&vec[0]`. It's been a long day.

Comment: vector doesn't have a c_str()